# Rails credentials files and Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 7
```

I am running into some issues using **[Rails.env.to_sym]**. Some config files understand it, and some do not.

Doing some research, it seems as if I can generate different credentials files, for each runtime environment. For instance:

```
rails credentials:edit --environment development
rails credentials:edit --environment test
```

Does this mean that Rails will pick the appropriate credentials file, based on the rails environment setting (test, development, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s correct — the main credentials file (`credentials.yml.enc`) is overwritten by environment-specific files.

If you run `bin/rails credentials:edit -h` from the command line, you’ll see this:

```
=== Environment Specific Credentials

The `credentials` command supports passing an `--environment` option to create an environment specific override. That override will take precedence over the global `config/credentials.yml.enc` file when running in that environment. So:

   bin/rails credentials:edit --environment development

will create `config/credentials/development.yml.enc` with the corresponding encryption key in `config/credentials/development.key` if the credentials file doesn't exist.
```

One tiny gotcha for me — I ran into an error trying to generate environment-specific credentials file (part of error below):

```
`binwrite': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - config/credentials/test.yml.enc.tmp
```

My fix was creating the empty folder first (`config/credentials`) and then re-running command (e.g., `bin/rails credentials:edit --environment test`)

Comment: Thank you. In my case the master key was nit created, only the config/credentials/development.yml.enc file

Comment: I came across the same error as @DanBrown and I was perplexed. Your tip (creating a directory) was a lifesaver! Ta.